# Как изменить ссылку на актуальную ревизию подмодуля?

Tags: git

Дано: есть репозиторий, у него есть подмодуль. Как сделать так чтобы при `submodule update` подтягивалась некая определенная версия подмодуля? То есть сейчас тянется из сабмодуля коммит скажем 34b4763, а я хочу чтобы по умолчанию тянулся коммит 59a8a83.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd path/to/submodule
git checkout 59a8a83
cd -
git add path/to/submodule
git commit -m "Changed submodule version."
```